# Is the Hausdorff measure of this disk equal to 0?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Consider a topological space $D^n$ homeomorphic to the closed unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $D^n$ is equipped with a topogically compatible metric that is intrinsic.

Is the $(n+1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure of $D^n$ equal to zero?

(A very close question to this would be: does $D^n$ have Hausdorff dimension $n$?)

The case $n=1$ is straightforward, because it is known that an intrinsic metric on a space homeomorphic to an interval makes the space isometric to an interval, so the $2$-dimensional Hausdorff measure would be 0.

Theorems of dimension theory that I've been looking at don't seem to apply here, and finding a counterexample seems complicated, since I'm assuming it would be fractal in nature.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Added:** Also, does the situation change if one assumes that $D^n$ is homeomorphic to the open unit ball instead of the closed unit ball?

Comment: If you have a dimension measure where $D^n$ doesn't have dimension $n$, I would say something is wrong with that dimension measure.

Comment: True, intuitively it should be $n$, but I don't know if there are any pathological examples assuming only that the metric is intrinsic.

Comment: Filled Koch snowflake is homeomorphic to closed ball (one way to see it is that Koch snowflake is a Jordan curve). But its Hausdorff dimension is $2 \ln(2)/ \ln(3)$, right?

Comment: @freakish I sincerely doubt that. It's contained in a 2-disc, and it contains a 2-disc, so if, as in this very problem, 2-discs indeed do have Haussdorff dimension 2, then the filled snowflake must have that too. If I recall, it is the _boundary_ of the snowflake that has dimension $\ln(4)/\ln(3)$.

Comment: @Arthur yes, you're right, it is the boundary. My mistake.

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer since there are subtleties that would need to be addressed about the boundary.  Certainly if you ask the same question about an ***open*** ball the answer is generally no, with a counter-example being the open unit ball in the Heisenberg group with its Carnot-Caratheodory metric - this has Hausdorff dimension $4$, despite being homeomorphic to $D^3$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_group for details).  But I haven't studied this in a long long time so don't want to say exactly what happens at the boundary.  Don't have a 2D counterexample offhand.

Comment: This might be a better reference than wikipedia for this: https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/carnot_caratheodory.pdf

Comment: @MW Dimension is "obviously not" homeomorphism invariant, since it's so dependent on a global notion of diameter measurements. And this is also not part of the question. We aren't asking about a space homeomorphic to $D^n$, we are asking about the actual space $D^n$, with the standard metric.

Comment: @Arthur the way I understood it is that the question is not about the standard metric (I am not even sure we can canonically give $D^n$ a metric) but about a general metric where all we know is that it's Topology is homeomorphic to the ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and that it is intrinsic

Comment: @Carlyle Oh, you're right. I completely misread the first sentence of the post.

Comment: @Arthur, don't worry, it happens to me daily

Comment: @MW Thank you for your amazing answer! I'm now looking at the paper to try to understand the details. Also, do you have any suspicion that the space $D^3$ you're mentioning has 4-dimensional Hausdorff measure equal to 0 (I first referred to the second question of my post as a stronger version, but then you answered the question negatively and I realized it wasn't really a stronger version because a space of Hausdorff dimension $d$ could also have $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure equal to 0. Sorry for the typo).

Comment: @mathplayer no it definitely has positive Hausdorff $4$-measure, in fact the Heisenberg group with cc metric is “Ahlfors $4$-regular”, meaning balls of radius $r$ have hausdorf $4$-measure comparable to $r^4$.

Comment: @MW Outstanding! I'm actually interested in both the case where $D^n$ is homeomorphic to the open unit ball or to the closed unit ball; I changed my post to reflect this. So, feel free to post your comments as an answer, in case you'd like to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Upgrading from comments]

In the case of an open ball, the answer is generally no, at least for $n\geq 3$.
In dimension $3$, a counterexample is any open subset homeomorphic to $D^3$ in the Heisenberg group $\mathbb H$, equipped with its [Carnot–Carathéodory (CC) metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Riemannian_manifold) $d_{CC}$.  Since the CC metric is intrinsic, and Ahlfors $4$-regular (balls of radius $r$ have Hausdorff $4$-measure comparable to $r^4$), every open subset of $\mathbb H$ has positive Hausdorff $4$-measure, and since $\mathbb H$ is a manifold, there is an open subset homeomorphic to the open ball.

We must be slightly cautious here, since strictly speaking, once we restrict to an open set $U\subset \mathbb H$, our original metric $d_{CC}$ need not be intrinsic any more (a shortest path may leave the open set), however, we can consider the induced length metric $d_{CC}'$ given by taking shortest paths in $U$.  It is not hard to show this is locally isometric to $d_{CC}$, so Hausdorff measure will be the same under either metric.

In dimensions higher than $3$, one could consider other [Carnot Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_group), or note that once we have a locally $4$-regular metric $d$ on $D^3$, then if $d_e$ is the Euclidean metric on $D^k$, then the metric $d'$ on $D^{3+k}\cong D^3\times D^k$ given by $d'((p_1,q_1),(p_2,q_2))=d(p_1,p_2)+d_e(q_1,q_2)$ is locally $(4+k)$-regular, so we have counterexamples for all dimensions greater than $3$.

The case of closed balls is a little more subtle, since a little work would need to be done to ensure that $d_{CC}$ induces a topologically equivalent length metric on $\overline{U}$.  I believe this is almost certainly true for reasonable open subsets $U$ of $\mathbb H$, but possibly not for an arbitrary open subset, if the boundary is sufficiently wild.

Finally, I don't know a counter-example in the case $n=2$, though I suspect there is one.